# Styling checked item in QTreeView

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreeview

How can I style checked item in QTreeView. I Have this code:

```
QTreeView::indicator:checked, QTableView::indicator:checked
{
    image: none;
}
QTreeView::item:checked, QTableView::item:checked
{
    color: rgb(120, 120, 120);
}
```

Indicator is displayed without image, however, checked item is still displayed with regular text color.